# c# MVC - Populate DropDownList from class property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dropdownlistfor

I'm working with EF and MVC, new stuff to me.
I have the following class:

```
 public class Client
{
    [Key]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

}
```

and I want to show in the View related to the "Create" ActionResult, a selectable DropDownList with all the categories to choose one.

I have a ViewModel also:

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

which I use in the controller:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
    {
        var db = new MyDBContext();
        var categories = db.Categories
                    .Select(x =>
                            new Category
                            {
                                CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                                Name = x.Name
                            });

        return new SelectList(categories, "Value", "Text");
    }
```

...and in the Create():

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new CategoryViewModel();
        model.Categories = GetCategories();
        return View(model);
    }
```

I dont know how to populate the dropdown in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(WHAT GOES HERE????)

        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks for rescuing me! (RE5 quote)

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories)` but your `GetCategories()` method is wrong and will throw an exception. Use `return db.Categories.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.CategoryId.ToString(), Text = x.Name });`

Answer (score 3):

There are different [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist(v=vs.118).aspx) but this is an option:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories)
```